# Elmah sends error mail on development server, but not on production

Tags: smtp, elmah

I am trying to set up Elmah so that it sends me an e-mail when a new error occurs. This works fine on my development server, but on the production server no e-mail is sent. The exception is logged on the production server, it's just the e-mail that does not get sent.

Here are my elmah configuration settings:

```
<elmah>
        <security allowRemoteAccess="yes"/>

        <errorMail
     from="<MYGOOGLELOGIN>@googlemail.com"
     to="<MYGOOGLELOGIN>@googlemail.com"
     subject="ERROR From Elmah"
     async="false"
     smtpPort="587"
     useSsl="true"
     smtpServer="smtp.gmail.com"
     userName="<MYGOOGLELOGIN>@googlemail.com"
     password="<MYGOOGLEPASSWORD>" />


</elmah>
```

I've tried different mail servers, both local and remote, and I tried both synchronous and asynchronous mail sending but to no avail.

Now I don't have the slightest idea how to proceed (apart from debugging Elmah on my production server, which seems like a lot of effort to set up). Please help!

Thanks,

Adrian

**Edit:** I might also add that I tried switching off the firewall on the production server, but that did not make any difference either.

Comment: Just shooting in the dark, but maybe it's a firewall problem on port 587? Can you try connecting to the SMTP server manually (using telnet or something) from the production server?

Comment: Good thinking, but I tried switching off the firewall already. No dice...

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a text book port blocking on a firewall somewhere (local or isp level)

try connecting to the smtp from the production box using command line telnet

instructions are here:
http://www.yuki-onna.co.uk/email/smtp.html

if you can't connect using the above method with port 587, then it is DEFINITELY a firewall issue - if not we can keep thinking, but does your servers application error log shown any failure from the message send?

Comment: As already mentioned in the OP comments, I tried switching off the firewall already. Also, I am able to send e-mail from the development machine through the same port to the same server. It can't be a firewall issue.

Comment: But have you tested with telnet. You really should as then you'll be able to see the SMTP error code. Trying to "send mail" does not give you this info

Comment: Doug: When using mail via smtp, the mail client does nothing else but to initiate a telnet session with the server in order to submit the e-mail. Just as shown in the article you have linked to. So implicitly I *have* actually tried a telnet session.

Comment: Adrian, i understand this - but unless you are actually looking at the exact response that the server is sending back as a reply, you are not aware of what is going on as ELMAH doesn't log the mail server error - by walking in ELMAHS shoes, you are able to replicate exactly. I really don't understand why this needed a downvote as it is good advice!